# Running selenium scripts in Linux container created using docker for windows

Tags: linux, docker, selenium-webdriver

I am able to run selenium scripts through the containers created using selenium - chrome, edge, and firefox images using docker for windows. Now, my requirement is I need to run the same scripts with same images in linux using docker for windows.

Could we use the Linux container created in docker for windows to run selenium scripts?
If possible, please let me know the steps.

Thanks